# How to deploy a bokeh application and not get 403 forbidden errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nginx, bokeh, gunicorn

I'm making a website that uses flask and bokeh. Here is a snippet from the dashboard.py file.

The bokeh graphs are showing up when replace www.****.org with localhost and run it locally.

However, when I deploy it on a (linode) server using NGINX and Gunicorn. The bokeh graphs don't show up and I get a 403 Forbidden error on the console.

Here are the errors

```
GET https://www.****.org:43733/bkapp/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=1001&bokeh-app-path=/bkapp&bokeh-absolute-url=https://www.****.org:43733/bkapp net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
GET https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.0.2.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 403
GET https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-2.0.2.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 403
```

Here is a snippet from my dashboard.py file

```
# can't use shortcuts here, since we are passing to low level BokehTornado
bkapp = Application(FunctionHandler(create_stocks_graph))

# This is so that if this app is run using something like "gunicorn -w 4" then
# each process will listen on its own port
sockets, port = bind_sockets("www.****.org", 0)

# initiate bokeh server
def bk_worker():
    # https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/1.1.0/examples/howto/server_embed/flask_gunicorn_embed.py
    asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())

    bokeh_tornado = BokehTornado({'/bkapp': bkapp}, extra_websocket_origins=["www.****.org"])
    bokeh_http = HTTPServer(bokeh_tornado)
    bokeh_http.add_sockets(sockets)

    server = BaseServer(IOLoop.current(), bokeh_tornado, bokeh_http)
    server.start()
    server.io_loop.start()

Thread(target=bk_worker).start()

# stocks graph script
script = server_document('https://www.****.org:%d/bkapp' % port)

# refresh custom_sectors before initially generating dashboard
current_user.summaries_sectors = pickle.dumps([])
```

and Here's my NGINX config:

```
server {
        server_name www.****.org;
location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.****.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.****.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = www.****.org) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        server_name www.****.org;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

}
```

Is there way to make the bokeh graphs work? I've spent countless hours trying to figure this out and I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Did you put those CSS files into the HTML yourself? Or was that something that Bokeh generated?

Comment: There are not separate CSS files for Bokeh 2.0+ so this must be something the OP added to a template.Those should just be removed. But I think the relevant error is the timeout. Are there any errors or relevant messages in the browser JS console, or network pane?

Comment: Also have you configured nginx (and possibly linode, I don't know) to forward websockets? Bokeh communicates over a websocket connection so if something is blocking that, that would certainly be an issue. The docs have information abotu configuring nginx https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#nginx